# Crash in ListView at AbsListView.obtainView for ListActivity

Tags: android, listview

I'm watching content updates on a ListActivity using a ContentObserver as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState)
   {
        super.onCreate(savedState);

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        Cursor cursor = cr.query(TrackHeader.CONTENT_URI, sTrackListProjection, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        this.mAdapter = new TrackHeaderDataAdapter(this, R.layout.track_list_item, cursor, sTrackListProjection, null);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        Handler handler = new Handler();

        mTrackHeaderObserver = new ContentObserver(handler) {

             @Override 
             public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() { 
                 return false;
             }

             @Override
             public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                 super.onChange(selfChange);
                 ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                 mAdapter.changeCursor(cr.query(TrackHeader.CONTENT_URI, sTrackListProjection, null, null, null));
              }
         };

      getContentResolver().registerContentObserver (TrackHeader.CONTENT_URI, true, mTrackHeaderObserver);
  }
```

This content observer seems to be ok -- it gets called back on the UI thread but I am getting the following random crash pretty predictably on the underlying ListView:

```
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at  android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1276)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1668)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:637)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1224)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1499)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1113)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:996)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-21 14:06:00.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(739):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 14:09:56.159: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(749): ERROR: thread attach failed
02-21 14:09:59.480: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(760): ERROR: thread attach failed
02-21 14:12:19.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778): ERROR: thread attach failed
02-21 14:12:22.779: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(789): ERROR: thread attach failed
02-21 14:12:26.479: ERROR/gralloc(51): [unregister] handle 0x3f13b8 still locked (state=40000001)
```

Anyone seen anything like this before -- been stumped on this one for a few days...

Tim

Comment: Hey Tim did you ever get this resolved? I'm seeing same messages in my log

Comment: If you are using getview method be very careful, as Cursoradaptor also has a method called getview..I burned my hands here for few hours..

Comment: @SaKet what is your solution btw ?

Answer (score 228):

I had a similar stack trace and discovered that I was returning a null from my getView() method in certain cases.

Comment: I had the same issue, and this is what was happening. I forgot to remove a null return in my adapter's getView.

Comment: Same with me.  A stray 'return null' at the bottom of my overridden ExpandableListAdapter was causing this.

Comment: Saved me quite the headache... Curse those stubbed out methods!

Comment: I completely forgot to implement my adapter!

Comment: Hi, I know this thread is old, but this is for anyone who may find this thread. I kept seeing this error, and everything in the code seemed ok; it wasn't until I noticed that some other minor exceptions also were happening behind the scenes. The apk was incorrectly formed. Stupid, and highly annoying, but once I did a clean build of the apk with "make" instead of "mm" that everything went magically away. HTH.

Comment: @YeLinAung I joined your party :)

Answer (score 11):

If you have a list and extend BaseAdapter or Adapter to get a custom list, make sure that getView returns a non-null value.

If you have a tabbed view and one of your fragment is a list that override Adapter/BaseAdapter and getView returns null you will get this problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a static class ViewHolder to store your view items in the adapter, you may forgot to set the viewHolder object as the tag of the convertView. E.g:

```
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_drivers_and_riders, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        holder.tvTime = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

In my case, I was not using a Cursor but having the same issue, I figured it out that i forgot to set the tag as viewHolder to convertView so when the first adapter views are created for the listview, it is ok but when you scroll and recycling mechanism works, it crashes since it can't restore the viewHolder from convertView.

Just in case, I wanted to mention.

Comment: Thanks a lot...it helped me, i did not setTag so it was generating exception. convertView.setTag(holder); it solved :)

Answer (score 3):

I have not used `changeCursor()`. And, since the query you used to create the `Cursor` is the same as the query you are using to "change" the cursor, I'd dump the `changeCursor()` call outright and just call `requery()` on the `Cursor` you have.

Comment: yeah, actually, i started with requery() and had the same issue.   any other ideas?