# Random NullPointerException. No Clue in Trace

Tags: android

I have been working on a project for a while now, working on it through the night, and the project had always been working, any smallish bugs I had managed to get rid of.

It was in a working state, I went for a bio-break and came back to this!!

```
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2163)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1638)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1996)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.widget.GridLayout.onLayout(GridLayout.java:1138)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
04-17 08:42:53.017: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I may have changed something before I had my break, but this is not giving me much of a clue as to where I should be looking for the Pointer Exception....

Can anyone shed some light on where else the problem may lie from this?

Thanks in advance...

EDIT!!!

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    WindowManager windowManager = getWindowManager();
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    if (display.getWidth() > display.getHeight()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.land_activity_menu);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    }
}


public void aboutClick(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class));
}

public void newsClick(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, NewsActivity.class));
}

public void coursesClick(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, CoursesActivity.class));
}

public void loginClick(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
}
```

Then the application crashes soon as newsactivity is launched...

```
 public class NewsActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

// globals... need to change these?
private ListView listview;
private List<RowItems> rowItems;
final int itemCount = 15;
String newsItemTitles[] = new String[itemCount];
String newsItemDates[] = new String[itemCount];
String newsItemDesc[] = new String[itemCount];
String newsItemHREFS[] = new String[itemCount];
String newsItemPicHREFS[] = new String[itemCount];

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Start Async for News
    getNewsTask();

}

private void getNewsTask() {
    new getNews().execute();
}

private class getNews extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    boolean service;
    CustomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(NewsActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Loading News...");
        pd.setMessage("Loading " + itemCount + " News Items");
        pd.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        startActivity(new Intent(NewsActivity.this,
                                MenuActivity.class));
                    }
                });
        pd.show();

    }
```

Im not entirely sure what would cause the crash here...

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3944534/1651233

Comment: seems like there is something wrong in getView implementation of Adapter ... are you returning null from getView ?

Comment: I think you should post your code to be helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, you will have this problem if you return null in getView() method of your adapter. Make sure you create a new instance of convertView if it is null.

Comment: You shouldn't put other people's comments as your own answer.

Comment: What if they did not put an answer and never will? Nothing to accept for the original poster.